# Create post request with data from html table rows and save each row separately Order-Products

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

can someone give me tip how to slove problem. Am building `Order Managment System` app using `PHP, MYSQL, HTML and JS`.
`Order` information is stored in one db table and
`Order Products` is sotred in second db table which cointains two foreign key (order_id and product_id). Order can have many products!

**What is problem**

The problem is that I don't know how to get html table rows and put that rows in array, and that array i need to send via `ajax` to `php` where i will process.

**I was thinking the following:**

1. When the user selects a product from the drop-down list, enters the quantity and presses the "ADD PRODUCT" button.
2. In javascript, I create an event for a button ('click') where after event is triggered I will dynamically create a new row in the table using js `insertRow()`.
3. In the columns of the rows I saved the values ​​in the form fields. Maybe I was wrong there.
   `id.innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="'+data[0]['id']+'" id="id-'+data[0]['id']+'";
4. Products is successfully added as rows with values ​​to the table.

I'm not asking you to do my job. I just want you to advise me how it should be done in the right way.

**HTML**

```
<table id="document_items_table">
   <thead class="table-light">
       <tr>
         <th width="10%">#</th>
         <th>Šifra</th>
         <th>Naziv</th>
         <th>Količina</th>
         <th>JM</th>
        </tr>
   </thead>                      
   <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 // add item to document
$("#btn_add_document_item").on('click', function(e) {

     var data = $('#select2-proizvodi').select2('data');

     // add table row

     var table = document.getElementById('document_items_table');
     var row = table.insertRow(-1);

     var id = row.insertCell(0);
     var code = row.insertCell(1);
     var name = row.insertCell(2);
     var qty = row.insertCell(3);
           

    row.setAttribute('id', 'row-'+table.rows.length);

    id.innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="'+data[0]['id']+'" id="id-'+data[0]['id']+'"  name="item[]["id"]" ;
    code.innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="'+data[0]['code']+'" name="item[]["code"]";
   name.innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="'+data[0]['text']+'"  name="item[]["name]";
  qty.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-input"  value="'+$("#kolicina_input").val()+'" name="kolicina[]["kolicina"]" ;
           
});
```

PHP is not a problem.

Check image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have done it personally :

What I understand : You want to be able to save mutiple lines in the same time (because each line is a diffrent product of the same order for exemple)

- You create a table where each line is a product and each cell of this line is the product info (name, qty, price, etc...)
- When you click "save" button it has to trigger an ajax request that will call a php page, this page will cretate a new order and return the id as a response to the request.
- Now you can loop throw your table rows, for each row you send an ajax request to a php page (data of this request is row cells + order_id you got previously)
- Your php will recieved data from the ajax request and store it in your db table (order product)

I hope it answer your question, if you need help to write a part of this code feel free to ask me ;)

Maxime

Comment: I know how to save multiple records and how to get last inert id. Problem is in js how to get table rows

Comment: I just gave an exempel below ;)

Answer (score 0):

How to get data froms table rows :

HTML :

```
<table id="table-products">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Label</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Product 1</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>35</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Product 2</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Product 3</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>99</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

JS :

```
let table = document.querySelector('#table-products');

let headers = [...table.rows[0].cells].map(th => th.innerText);
for(let row of [...table.rows].slice(1, table.rows.length)) {
    let product = Object.fromEntries(new Map([...row.cells].map((cell, i) => [headers.at(i), cell.innerText])));
    console.log(product);
}
```